The mock of pytest doesn't work on my controller, just in scope of test
I mock a package and on the scope of the test the mock works but on my file of constants when is called by controller, the mock doesn't work.
test_server.py
from dotenv import dotenv_values

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_vars():
    def returns(_):
        return {
            "CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME": "5"
        }
    with mock.patch("dotenv.dotenv_values", returns):
        yield


class TestShowClientsOnline:
    def test_should_not_show_an_expired_health_check_datetime(self, mocker, mock_mongodb):
        print(dotenv_values('.env')) # {"CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME": "5"}
        request = client.get(f"{namespace}/client/online")

constants.py
from dotenv import dotenv_values


config = dotenv_values(".env")


MONGO_URL = config["MONGO_URL"]
MONGO_DB = config["MONGO_DB"]

IPV4_REGEX = r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME = int(config["CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME"]) + 1

routers/server.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Query, Body
from typing import Annotated

from use_cases import AddTaskUseCase, RemoveTaskUseCase
from models import parse_host
from utils import date_in_range, str_to_date
from constants import IPV4_REGEX, CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME


router = APIRouter(prefix="/server")

@router.get("/client/online", status_code=200)
async def get_clients_online(
    request: Request
):
    collection = request.app.database["host"]

    full_clients = collection.find({})

    clients_online = []

    for client in full_clients:
        last_health_check_datetime = str_to_date(client["health_check_datetime"])

        if date_in_range(
            date=last_health_check_datetime,
            max_minute=CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME
        ):
            clients_online.append(parse_host(client))

    print(CLIENT_HEALTH_CHECK_LOOP_TIME) # 16

    return clients_online

As you can see, the mock works within the scope of the test but when the controller calls the constants.py file, it returns the real environment variable.
